# Error trying to call array string from other activity

Tags: java, android

This code is for call an array string from MainActivity.java class.

```
    TextView infoEnviada;
    infoEnviada = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reslt);
    String[] array = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("resultados");
    infoEnviada.setText(array);
}
```

The problem is in line `infoEnviada.setText(array);` because it says: `Cannot resolve method setText(java.lang.String[])` I need help, because i want to call that string, and print it in a ListView or TextView, if it's possible.

Error log:

```
03-06 16:54:45.814 6978-6978/com.example.pablo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at com.example.pablo.myapplication.encuesta$1.onClick(encuesta.java:59)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17088)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

On click event code:

```
Button sig = (Button) findViewById(R.id.env); // cargo el boton
    sig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            EditText preg5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            EditText preg4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            EditText nom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            Spinner cur = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerp);
            RadioGroup gruporadio = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Grupo1);
            RadioGroup gruporadio2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Grupo2);
            RadioGroup gruporadio3 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Grupo3);
            String strNombre = nom.getText().toString();
            String curso =  cur.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String strPregCinco = preg5.getText().toString();
            String strPregCuatro = preg4.getText().toString();

            if(gruporadio.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1 || gruporadio2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1  || gruporadio3.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1 )
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"¡No marcaste ninguna respuesta!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else if (strNombre.matches("") || strPregCinco.matches("") || strPregCuatro.matches(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"¡Dejaste campos vacíos!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else
            {
                ListView listaresultados = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.reslt);
                ArrayList respuestas = new ArrayList();
                ArrayAdapter adaptador2 = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, respuestas);
                listaresultados.setAdapter(adaptador2);
                respuestas.add(strNombre);
                respuestas.add(curso);
                respuestas.add(strPregCuatro);
                respuestas.add(strPregCinco);
                Intent intent = new Intent (encuesta.this, res8.class);
                intent.putExtra("resultados", respuestas);
                startActivity(intent);
                Intent pas = new Intent(encuesta.this, MainActivity.class);
                Toast.makeText(context,"¡Encuesta enviada!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(pas);
            }
        }
    });
```

The error seems to be at line 59. But actually gruporadio, gruporadio2, and gruporadio3 exists.

```
RadioGroup gruporadio = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Grupo1);
                RadioGroup gruporadio2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Grupo2);
                RadioGroup gruporadio3 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Grupo3);

<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/Grupo1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1/2 hora a 1 hora" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1 hora o 2 horas" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2 horas o más" />
    </RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/Grupo2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1/2 hora a 1 hora" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1 hora o 2 horas" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2 horas o más" />
    </RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/Grupo3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Norte de Bogotá (calle 72 en adelante)" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Suba (noroccidente)" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Centro - Chapinero - Teusaquillo" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Alrededores de Bogotá" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sur de Bogotá" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Occidente (Puente Aranada - Fontibón - Engativá)" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: `setText()` method is for a `CharSequence` - follow the methods' usage!

Comment: can you paste your on click event code?

Comment: Yep, it is done.

Comment: which line is your '59th' line?

Comment: From 56 to 59: `if(gruporadio.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1 || gruporadio2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1  || gruporadio3.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1 )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"¡No marcaste ninguna respuesta!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }` of encuesta.java

Comment: so it seems that 'gruporadio' or 'gruporadio2' or 'gruporadio3' is null, that it would mean that at least one of theme are not exist in your layout!

Comment: so are you sure that you attach this layout to your activity?

Comment: Yep, here: `RadioGroup gruporadio = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Grupo1);
                RadioGroup gruporadio2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Grupo2);
                RadioGroup gruporadio3 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Grupo3);`

Comment: You seem to have two different issues here. Please only post one problem per question. If you resolved the original issue, you should accept the answer which helped the most. Then post a new question for the next issue.

Comment: I dont know how many issues i have, so dont tell me that because i dont know how many issues, or which issues i have.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is in line infoEnviada.setText(array); because it says:
>   Cannot resolve method setText(java.lang.String[]) I need help, because
>   i want to call that string, and print it in a ListView or TextView, if
>   it's possible.

the error occurs because you're trying to pass an `array` to the `setText(...)` `method` which is not valid.

try this:

```
infoEnviada.setText(Arrays.toString(array))
```

Comment: Yes, i did it now. But the problem now is that the app crashed when else execute

Comment: This else: `else
{
ListView listaresultados = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.reslt);
ArrayList respuestas = new ArrayList();
ArrayAdapter adaptador2 = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, respuestas);
listaresultados.setAdapter(adaptador2);
respuestas.add(strNombre);
respuestas.add(curso);
respuestas.add(strPregCuatro);
respuestas.add(strPregCinco);
Intent intent = new Intent (encuesta.this, res8.class);
intent.putExtra("resultados", respuestas);
startActivity(intent);
Intent pas = new Intent(encuesta.this, MainActivity.class);`
...

Comment: ...`Toast.makeText(context,"¡Encuesta enviada!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
startActivity(pas);}`

Comment: that doesn't mention any error.... also update your question with the error you've got rather than pasting it here. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the problem in your code is that [settext](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) method dosnt take arrays as parameter... pass the array as String instead

```
infoEnviada.setText(Arrays.toString(array));
```